# Events in C++

Tags: c++

I'm not sure how to look for this online... I think they might be called something different in C++

I want to have a simple event system, somthing like

```
event myCustomEvent;
myCustomEvent.subscribe( void myHandler(string) );
myCustomEvent.fire("a custom argument");
// myHandler prints out the string passed in the first argument


event myNewCustomEvent;
myNewCustomEvent.subscribe( void myNewHandler(int) );
myNewCustomEvent.fire(10);
// myHandler prints 10
```

I can do this pretty easily with a simple class -- but when i want to have an event that passes a different type or amount of arguments to the subscriber i have to write, and define an entirely new event class.. I figure there has to be some library, or maybe even something native in Visual C++ 2008 that will work something similar to this. It's basicly just an implementation of the Observer pattern, so it can't be too impossible to do in C++

This really makes me appreciate how nice it is in JavaScript not to have to worry about the arguments you are passing.

Tell me if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use [sigslot](http://sigslot.sourceforge.net/) for exactly this purpose.

Comment: I'm glad you reminded me of this... I didn't understand what signals/slots were when I came across it (still thinking events/subscribers)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. stackoverflow is amazing.

Answer (score 20):

Take a look at the boost [signal](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/signals.html) library.  Combined with the [function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/function.html) and [bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/bind/bind.html) libraries, you can do exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 9):

The observer pattern from the GOF is pretty much what you want.

In the book, it has C++ code for this...

Also, as always, Boost has stuff you can make use of as well

Comment: I'm looking into the book now. Boost calls them signals and slots I think.. and it seems they were doing a whole lot more than I needed. I may end up having to go more deeply into that though.

Comment: Besides the signals and slots in .NET (Visual C++) you have events and delegates. you can read more on them :)

Comment: Why was this voted -1? That's absurd, this is a valid (and good) solution.

Comment: I originally posted a one line reply, I'm picking I got downvoted then,  but before I noticed that I thought, I didnt really give too much details. Still haven't really,  what I've done in production code is created a templated based observer pattern like event system to handle different event types

Comment: I keep reading about templated approaches, but I have no idea how to implement them.

Comment: I'd say here you'd use template< class PayLoad > class Event : public PayLoad {}. Of course, you could also just derive the other way round and spare the template. It's not so neat, though. :)

Comment: within the decleration of the fire() function you would just use public fire(PayLoad); ? and declare and event like event myEvent<float>?

Comment: You would create different kinds of PayLoad classes and have them contain, for example, float foo. But I strongly suggest going for a derived class rather than a templated approach for your needs. Define a Event-class and then define a class FooEvent : public Event { float foo; } Use references!

Answer (score 7):

There is a native Visual C++ [event system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f01ek09.aspx).  It's mostly for COM, but it has native C++ support too.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee2k0a7d.aspx):

```
[event_source(native)]
class CSource {
public:
   __event void MyEvent(int nValue);
};

[event_receiver(native)]
class CReceiver {
public:
   void MyHandler1(int nValue) {
      printf_s("MyHandler1 was called with value %d.\n", nValue);
   }

   void MyHandler2(int nValue) {
      printf_s("MyHandler2 was called with value %d.\n", nValue);
   }

   void hookEvent(CSource* pSource) {
      __hook(&CSource::MyEvent, pSource, &CReceiver::MyHandler1);
      __hook(&CSource::MyEvent, pSource, &CReceiver::MyHandler2);
   }

   void unhookEvent(CSource* pSource) {
      __unhook(&CSource::MyEvent, pSource, &CReceiver::MyHandler1);
      __unhook(&CSource::MyEvent, pSource, &CReceiver::MyHandler2);
   }
};

int main() {
   CSource source;
   CReceiver receiver;

   receiver.hookEvent(&source);
   __raise source.MyEvent(123);
   receiver.unhookEvent(&source);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use [libsigc++](http://libsigc.sourceforge.net/). It's native for gtkmm.

A simple example losely adapted from the [tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/libsigc++-tutorial/stable/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sigc++/sigc++.h>

using namespace std;

class AlienDetector {
public:
        void run ();
        sigc::signal<void> signal_detected;
};

void warn_people () {
        cout << "There are aliens in the carpark!" << endl;
}

void AlienDetector::run () {
        signal_detected.emit ();
}

int main () {
        AlienDetector mydetector;
        mydetector.signal_detected.connect (sigc::ptr_fun (warn_people));
        mydetector.run ();
}
```

It also provides a mechanism to connect member-functions of specific objects to signals using sigc::mem_fun instead of sigc::ptr_fun:

```
sigc::mem_fun (someobject, &SomeClass::some_method);
```

This pretty much provides anything that is possible with GLib-signals.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple C++ delegate implementation I used on an Arduino project. It relies on a smart pointer to allow for a cleaner syntax when attaching event handlers. It supports only one handler but this can easily be extended by implementing some container of EventDelegates.

```
template<typename TSender, typename TArgument>
class EventDelegate {
private:
  struct Callable {
    virtual ~Callable() {}
    virtual void Call(TSender* sender, TArgument* argument) = 0;
  };

  template<typename TClass>
  struct CallableImpl : public Callable {
    TClass* _instance;
    void (TClass::*_method)(TSender*, TArgument*);

    CallableImpl(TClass* instance, void (TClass::*method)(TSender*, TArgument*))
      : _instance(instance), _method(method) {}

    void Call(TSender* sender, TArgument* argument) {
      (_instance->*_method)(sender, argument);
    }
  };

protected:
  RefCountedPtr<Callable> _callable; // smart pointer

public:
  template<typename TClass>
  EventDelegate(const TClass* instance, void (TClass::*method)(TSender* sender, TArgument* argument))
    : _callable(new CallableImpl<TClass>(instance, method)) {}

  EventDelegate()
    : _callable(0) {}

  ~EventDelegate() {
  }

  void operator()(TSender* sender, TArgument* argument) {
    if (_callable) {
      _callable->Call(sender, argument);
    }
  }
};
```

Here is how you can use it

```
class Button {
public:
  typedef EventDelegate<Button, ButtonClickArgs> ClickEvent;
  ClickEvent OnClick;

protected:
  RaiseClick() {
    ButtonClickArgs args(...);
    OnClick(this, &args)
  }
};

class App {
public:
  App() {
    // Here the smart pointer ensures that the Callable isn't
    // destroyed when the Button::ClickEvent object on the stack 
    // goes out of scope
    g_button->OnClick = Button::ClickEvent(this, &App::ClickHandler)
  }

  ~App() {
    g_button->OnClick = Button::ClickEvent();
  }
protected:
  void ClickHandler(Button* button, ButtonClickArgs* args) {
    ...
  }
};
```