# Redefine Method In Class C++

Tags: c++, class, methods

I've been trying to create buttons for my new game in c++, and I have created a class for them holding data. I need to be able to allocate a method to each button click class. For example, let's say I have ten buttons, I need each one to output a different word when it is clicked.

```
class button{
    float position;


    float scale;

    void on_click();
};

button new_button;
new_button.on_click = {
    std::cout << "HELLO" << std::endl;
}
```

How would I get something like this to work? 
Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238738/events-in-c

Comment: Words are data. Objects carry data. Different objects of the same class may carry different data. You don't need to create a separate method for each piece of data.

Comment: The right solution is to store the string as data and output that. The direct answer to your question is to use `std::function`.

Comment: On any platfom, you can find the native api that creates a windowing framework as well as event/signal/callback management. What platform are you using? If you want to build up from scratch, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing your code by taking your question literally would be using a `std::function` member as in

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct button { 
    using callback = std::function<void()>;    
    callback on_click;
    button(callback f) : on_click(f) {};    
    void click() { on_click(); }
};

int main() {
    button b1{[](){ std::cout << "b1\n"; }};
    b1.click();
}
```

However, if the only difference is the text that is going to be printed, you simply store the string to be printed with the button

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct button { 
    std::string message;
    button(std::string s) : message(s) {};    
    void click() { std::cout << message; }
};

int main() {
    button b1{"b1\n"};
    b1.click();
}
```